# Softmax backpropagation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation, softmax

I know there are similar questions out there, but none of the answers really helped me. I'm working on an own neural network implementation and I want to implement the softmax activation function. I'm using backpropagation as the learning algorithm to train the network.

I learned that the softmax doesn't have a vector, but a matrix as its derivative. However I'm not sure how to apply that knowledge to the algorithm.

To calculate the error signal of an output neuron, the formula I use looks like this:

$$\delta_j=\varphi'(net_j)\cdot(o_j-t_j)$$

Where $\delta$ is the error signal, $\varphi$ is the activation function, $net$ is the netinput, $o$ is the output and $t$ is the target value.

This works fine for all activation functions with a vector derivative, but since the softmax' derivative is a $n\times n$ matrix I don't know how to interpret it.

As far as I understood everything right so far, that would mean that for every neuron there are $n$ different derivatives. How do I use them to calculate the error signals?

I hope I formulated my problem in an understandable way, if not feel free to correct me as english is not my native language. I hope y'all can help me. Thank you!

Comment: The goal of backprop is to calculate the gradient of the *loss function* (which produces a scalar) w.r.t. the parameters. The way to handle a softmax output layer is no different than how to handle any other kind of layer (e.g. relu/tanh hidden layers). I.e. use the chain rule. If you want to write things out in matrix form, you'll find it useful to think of the chain rule in terms of jacobian-vector products. The  'matrix of derivatives' you mentioned is the jacobian.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your response. I still go to school and never really worked with the jacobian before. Could you explain it in more detail / give me some good resources to really understand what it is about? I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: @user20160 Or, if you don't have the time to do so, could you give me an example on the backpropagation with softmax with specific values?